# Как сделать на flex

Tags: css3, html5, flexbox

Как сделать двух колоночный макет на flex.Одна колонка фотография другая текст адаптивным.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.flex {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #000;
}

.text {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla itaque, earum quas. Accusantium labore, ab dolorum aliquam sint atque eligendi autem, iste qui amet similique provident veniam nostrum perspiciatis tempore.</div>
  <div class="img">
  </div>
</div>
```